# How to tokenize / split data from .csv files containing days and random numbers in C?

Tags: c, file-io, tokenize

I am trying to tokenize data from c file containing random days and numbers.
For example, data:

```
Thursday,60
Tuesday,45
Wednesday,80
Monday,14
Saturday,73
Tuesday,3
Saturday,29 
.
.
.   
Friday,71
Saturday,98
```

My main intention is to grab these data and do like:

```
Sunday: (Total of numbers sunday has in data)
Monday: (Total of numbers monday has in data)
Tuesday: (Total of numbers tuesday has in data)
.
.
.
Saturday: (Total of numbers saturday has in data)
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend trying [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ man -k token
strsep (3)           - extract token from string
strtok (3)           - extract tokens from strings
strtok_r (3)         - extract tokens from strings
tc-htb (8)           - Hierarchy Token Bucket
tc-tbf (8)           - Token Bucket Filter
wcstok (3)           - split wide-character string into tokens
$
```

`strtok` is a C Standard function and is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to a problem like this is to:

1) Read in the data (stdio.h). See http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/webmonkeys/book/c_guide/2.12.html

2) Use Regular expressions to get the day of the week (regex.h). See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html. In this case, you could write a really simple regex.

3) Have a int[] of size 7

4) Use the regex from (2) to get the number and increment the corresponding element of the array

Answer (score 0):

1. Read each line into a buffer using `fgets`
2. Tokenize the buffer using `strtok`
3. Convert the number token to an integer value using `strtol`
4. Add that value to the running total for that particular day

That's about as simple as it gets.